# Conditional expectation from $\mathcal{A}\rtimes_r\Gamma$ onto $\mathcal{A}\rtimes_r H$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

I wish to show the following: Let $\Gamma$ be a discrete group, $H$ a subgroup of $\Gamma$ and $\mathcal{A}$ be a unital $\Gamma$-$C^*$-algebra. I want to prove that the map $E_H: C_c(\Gamma,\mathcal{A})\to C_c(\Gamma,\mathcal{A})$, defined by
$$E\left(\sum_s a_ss\right)=\sum_{s\in H}a_ss$$ extends to a continuous map from $\mathcal{A}\rtimes_r\Gamma$ onto $\mathcal{A}\rtimes_r H$.

I follow the argument illustrated in Brown-Ozawa which shows that the canonical conditional expectation $E:\mathcal{A}\rtimes_r\Gamma\to \mathcal{A}$ is continuous

Without any loss of generality, let us say that $\mathcal{A}$ has a faithful covariant representation inside $\mathbb{B}(\mathcal{H})$. I resort to using Fell’s absorption principle. Using this principle, we view $\mathcal{A}\rtimes_{\alpha,r}\Gamma$ as a sub-algebras of $\mathbb{B}(\mathcal{H})\otimes C_r^*(\Gamma)$.

Now, under this identification, that $$E_H=(\text{id}\otimes\mathbb{E}_H)|_{\mathcal{A}\rtimes_r\Gamma}$$

,where $\mathbb{E}_H:C_r^{\star}(\Gamma)\to C_r^*(H)$ is the canonical conditional expectation.

Please let me know if I missed something here.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Is $H$ a subgroup of $\Gamma$?

Comment: Yes. It is. $H$ is a subgroup.

Comment: This looks ok to me.